# BackGround color problems

Tags: css

Here is my CSS Code

```
body{
font-family: 'lucida grande' , tahoma, verdana, arian, sans-serif;
 background-color:body {
 background-color:#C0C0C0;
} 
}
```

the background colour has been set to black but i want it grey (C0C0C0) 
is there anything that can effect this or overwrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the inner body block for to define background-color , just only outer one.

```
body{
  font-family: 'lucida grande' , tahoma, verdana, arian, sans-serif;
  background-color:#C0C0C0;
}
```